# Terraform - Cloudwatch event target not working as expected with timestamp()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to trigger a lambda every hour via cloudwatch event to perform some action.

Cloudwatch event should send 2 parameters `from_timestamp` and `to_timestamp` as input to lambda so that lambda can fetch some details between the timestamps.

For this in terraform, I created `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` and `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` resources like below.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "lambda_data_fetcher-schedule" {
  name                = "lambda_data_fetcher-schedule"
  description         = "Trigger data fetching lambda"
  schedule_expression = ""cron(10 7-23 ? * MON-FRI *)""
}
```

and

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "lambda_data_fetcher-target" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.lambda_data_fetcher-schedule.name
  arn  = <ARN of the lambda>
  input = jsonencode({
    from_timestamp = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z", timeadd(timestamp(), "-1h10m"))
    to_timestamp   = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z", timeadd(timestamp(), "-10m"))
  })
}
```

This is triggering the lambda based on the schedule provided in `schedule_expression`.
But `from_timestamp` and `to_timestamp` are static and is not changing at all.
Its always same value.
I want the values to change based on the time the event gets triggered.

Any clues why its happening like this

Comment: timestamp() is always going to be the time when the terraform plan got applied. Can you instead on your lambda code get the current system date when it gets executed?

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz For flexibility, decided to take input from the events. If not `timestamp()` is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post the code in your lambda. You should be able to achieve the same using lambda code only if I understand correctly.